# como comparar duas matrizes e trazer os valores diferentes?

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer o esquema de criar um loop de 1 a 70 por exemplo

no banco irá retornar

1
10
11
20
39
50
67
69

de 1 a 70 só que irá tudo, só irá trazer alguns numeros entre 1 e 70 .

estou tentando criar um loop usando o for de 1 a 70 e comparar com os valores mostrado acima que retorna do banco, eu preciso mostrar na tela os valores de 1 a 70 que não tem no banco, ou seja, que não tem no banco seria possível fazer isso?

Segue o código:

```
$aleatorio = rand(1, 70);
echo $aleatorio."<br>";
$recorte = $valor."_".$aleatorio;


$query = mysqli_query($con,"select material_name_crop from qe.etiquetas_recortadas_aoi where material_name_crop = '$recorte' and line = '$pkg' and brand = '$brand'") or die("erro na query");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($rows < 1){
    echo $recorte." - ".$pkg." - ".$brand." S";
}else{
    $pesq = mysqli_query($con,"select material_name_crop from qe.etiquetas_recortadas_aoi where material_name_crop like '%$valor%' and line = '$pkg' and brand = '$brand'") or die("erro na query");
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($pesq);
    echo "Total ".$total."<br><hr>";
    $count = 0;
    while($recorte = mysqli_fetch_array($pesq)){
        $count = $count+1;
        $content = explode("_",$recorte[0]);
        $t = $content[1];

        //print_r($content);
        for($i=0;$i<=70;$i++){

            $j[] = $i;
            //echo $j[$i];
            $result = array_search($j[$i], $content[1]);
            echo $result;

    //      echo array_diff($val)."  -   ";
        }
        echo "<br>".$count." - ".$content[1]."      /       ";

        //print_r($j);


    }
        echo "<br>".$count." - ".$content[1]."      /       ";

        //print_r($j);


    }
    //echo $recorte[0]." - ".$pkg." - ".$brand." N";
}
```

Comment: Eu recomendaria que desde já busque [edit] sua pergunta e melhorar o texto, principalmente utilizando pontuações. Está praticamente ilegível e incompreensível.

Comment: minha duvida é simples gostaria de saber se consigo trazer informações diferentes comparando duas arrays

Answer (score 0):

Tu pode utilizar a função `in_array`, onde ela vai checar se o valor não está dentro do `array` (no teu caso, seriam as informações vindo do banco).

```
// Armazena os dados vindo do banco em um array como este
$array_banco = array(1, 4, 7, 8, 2, 90);

for($i = 1; $i <= 70; $i++) {
   // Checa se o valor do for nao esta dentro do array
   if(!in_array($i, $array_banco)) {
        echo $i . ' nao esta dentro do array';
   }
}
```

Comment: Não seria `for($i = 1; $i <= 70; $i++) {`  para não retornar valor 0(zero)

Comment: Sim sim, coloquei errado ali. Já arrumei, valeu pelo aviso.